Irregularities in Moment of inertia of torus
This is NOT a question regarding the derivation of the moment of inertia of a torus, but rather an irregularity which I find in it. I am most probably wrong, but can't see where. It would be helpful to point it out.
As per Wikipedia(and answers here on SE),

My doubt thus: Consider a limiting case of the torus, a sphere. In this case, it would be equivalent to substituting $b$ as $0$ in the expression given.(Assuming rotation about its central axis)
When $b=0$, we get a sphere of radius $a$, which has a moment of inertia as $\frac{2}{5}ma^2$. But here, we get its moment of inertia as $\frac{3}{4}ma^2$.
A reason as to why this happens, I guessed, was that the density would not remain constant. But even then(I did the calculations) it doesn't match.
Why does this specific case not add up? Is it just that we can't substitute $b=0$ in the given expression? If so, why?

In order to understand why, it is necessary to understand the derivation of the given formula. The volume element of the torus in the usual coordinate convention is $\mathrm{d}V = (b+r\cos\theta)\mathrm{d}\phi(r\mathrm{d}\theta)\mathrm{d}r$ and the moment of inertia is therefore
$$\int \rho(b+r\cos\theta)^2 \mathrm{d}V = 2\pi\rho\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\int_0^a r(b+r\cos\theta)^3 \mathrm{d}r\mathrm{d}\theta  = \rho\left(2\pi^2ba^2\right)\frac{1}{4}\left(3a^2+4b^2\right).$$
Therefore, we see that in order to arrive at the given formula, the substitution $\rho\left(2\pi^2ba^2\right)=m$ is needed i.e. we need the fact that the volume of a torus is $2\pi^2ba^2$. But if you set $b=0$, the volume becomes zero and this step is no longer valid. In other words, the reason the volume (resp. moment of inertia) becomes zero is because upon setting $b=0$, the $r$ and $\theta$ integrals separate and the $\theta$ integrand becomes $\cos\theta$ (resp. $\cos^3\theta$). The limits then cover the sphere twice: once for $\theta\in(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$ and once for $\theta\in[-\pi,-\pi/2)\cup(\pi/2,\pi]$, giving two copies of opposite sign which cancel out.
The way to obtain the moment of inertia of a sphere from this point is to change the limits of the $\theta$ integral to only include the positive part, i.e. $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$, giving
$$2\pi\rho\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\int_0^a r(r\cos\theta)^3 \mathrm{d}r\mathrm{d}\theta$$
which you can check is the correct result.

A simple answer here.
To remain the shape of "torus", $b \geq a$.
When $b=a$, the torus is without a hole in the center, but still a valid torus.
If $b<a$, it is not a torus anymore.

Yes. It would not be a torus. But, consider a thin ring instead. This is equivalent to substituting $a=0$ in the given expression, and it matches with the correct moment of inertia, with a ring. Why does it work here?

A thin ring is still a torus, with small $a$. That's why it works.
If you want to remain a torus when $b \rightarrow 0$, then $a \rightarrow 0$ as well, the mass and thus the moment of inertia both go to $0$ as well.
